# Alterar fonte de letra da aplicação toda sem alterar o tamanho(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Boas,
queria arranjar uma forma de alterar a fonte de letra da app toda(Swift) em poucas linhas de código.
Neste momento tenho

```
extension UILabel {
   var substituteFontName : String {
        get { return self.font.fontName }
        set { self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font.pointSize) }
}
```

e depois no AppDelegate em didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UILabel.appearance().substituteFontName = "Roboto-Medium"
```

mas não está a funcionar, pois da erro no extension

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

sou novo na linguagem, alguém me consegue ajudar?
Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 0):

A partir `swift 4` você pode alterar a fonte sem precisar alterar o tamanho.

**Swift 4**

```
  UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle(rawValue: "Roboto-Medium"))
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
 UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle(rawValue: "Roboto-Medium"))
```

Comment: esta solução não me está  a resolver o problema, pois eu pretendo alterar a fonte de todas as labels... coisa que não esta a acontecer

Answer (score 0):

Vê se isso funciona para você

```
extension UILabel {
    var defaultFont: UIFont {
        get { return self.font }

        set {
            guard let font  = self.font else {
                return
            }

            self.font = UIFont(name: self.defaultFont.fontName, size: font.pointSize)
        }
    }
}

UILabel.appearance().defaultFont = UIFont.init(name: "Courier-Bold", size: 25)!
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor solução para você é ter um `Singleton` com suas fontes e sempre que você inicializar um label, você pergunta para esse `Singleton` qual fonte você deve usar.

Ou, você pode usar [swizzling](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/method-swizzling-in-ios-swift-1f38edaf984f) para mudar a fonte default de `UILabels` e `UITextViews` Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15328022/4307080

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (Swizzling)

- (UIFont *)swizzledFont;

@end


#import "UILabel+Swizzling.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UILabel (Swizzling)

- (UIFont *)swizzledFont
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Light" size:[[self swizzledFont] pointSize]];
}

+ (void)load
{
    Method original, swizzled;

    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(font));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzledFont));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

@end
```